# What is the number of favorable case of this problem?

Tags: probability

Here is the problem.

> There are balls numbered $1, 2, 3, \dots, N$ in the box. You should take out a ball, write down the ball's number, then it is returned to the box. This action will be repeated $n$ times, so $n$ numbers will be written down. Ask the probability of these number arranged in the ascending order.

I know the number of all possible cases is ${ N }^{ n }$, but I’m no idea about the favorable cases. I find an answer in the net.
$$P=\frac { \frac { N\cdot \left( N-1 \right) \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot n }{ n! }  }{ { N }^{ n } } $$
If the answer is correct,why?

Comment: What do you expect the probability to be when the number of balls drawn ($n$) is one?

Comment: @PaulAljabar what do you mean?

Comment: I think Paul means that for *n* = 1 the formula should give P = 1, but it doesn't, so it cannot be correct.
Hoever it is not too far off. Think of it this way - a favourable drawing must satisfy two conditions:
1. all *n* balls drawn must have different numbers
2. the *n* balls must be drawn in a specific sequence - 3,5,7 is good, but any other ordering of 3, 5 and 7 is bad.

Comment: What does "pull back" mean?

Comment: @Mathemagical  If you take out a ball, you need to put it back this time

Comment: I believe the intended formula may have been $\frac{N(n-1) \cdots (N-n+1)}{N^n}/n!,$ which seems to take care of @PaulAljabar's objection.

Comment: @BruceET I think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the birthday problem $\frac{N(n-1) \cdots (N-n+1)}{N^n}$ is the probability
that all integers are different. Then, assuming all arrangements to be equally
likely, one can divide by $n!$ to count as favorable only cases in which the different integers are in
ascending order.

It is feasible to simulate this for choices of $N$ and $n$ that lead
to probabilities above 0.01 or so. Then several different simulations I tried match the result $\frac{N(n-1) \cdots (N-n+1)}{N^n}/n!.$

---

In case it is of interest, here is the code for simulation in R statistical
software. With a million iterations, it is reasonable to expect
two or three place accuracy. [The function `diff` takes $r-1$ differences of the $r$-vector
returned by `sample`. The result is 'favorable' precisely when all
differences are positive.]

```
set.seed(2017)
N= 100;  r = 3
(prod(N:(N-r+1))/factorial(r))/N^r
## 0.1617

x = replicate( 10^6,  sum(diff(sample(1:N, r, repl=T))>0)  )
mean(x==r-1)
##  0.162211   # 95% margin of simulation error 0.0007
```